# scale some (but not all) tasks in ECS cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I have a very simple `docker-compose` for `locust`. It consists of one `master` (which is basically a webserver for a client) and one `slave` (which is a client that actually performs load testing, which is what locust is for).

```
version: "3"

services:
  locust-master:
    image: chapkovski/locust
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    environment:
      LOCUST_MODE: master


  locust-slave:
    image: chapkovski/locust
    "links": [
      "locust-master"
    ]
    environment:
      LOCUST_MODE: slave
      LOCUST_MASTER_HOST: locust-master
      LOCUST_MASTER_PORT: 5557
```

Everything works on AWS ECS. But now I would like to have multiple `slaves` connected to the same `master`, and I can't figure out how to do this. Because when I try to scale up the tasks, that results in an error due to the fact that ports are already busy. Which is obvious because scaling up this task definition makes ECS agent to have several masters at the same port.

When I try to split master and slave so I would have two tasks, and I would be able to scale up only the 'slave' one, then of course they cannot communicate, and the master does not see any clients.

So what is the correct way of scaling up only 'client' part, if, let's say I need 20 clients and one master?

Answer (score 1):

You can not scale services with predefined port, if you do so you will get error `Ports are already busy`.

You have to option to resolve this issue.

- One service per EC2 instance ( not good enough but way around)
- Dynamic port binding

With the second option, ECS agent assigns a dynamic port which not conflict with any occupied port so can scale as many tasks as you want.

[image]

You need set host port *0* in port mapping section.
[image]

[understanding-dynamic-port-mapping-in-amazon-ecs-with-application-load-balancer](https://medium.com/@mohitshrestha02/understanding-dynamic-port-mapping-in-amazon-ecs-with-application-load-balancer-bf705ee0ca8e)

```
"portMappings": [
    {
        "containerPort": 3000,
        "hostPort": 0
    }
 ]
```

Comment: thank you so much! I probably explained what I had in mind in a messy way. So there is one service named 'server' and one service that connects to server named 'slave'. And I wonder how I can scale up only 'slave' so I would have 10 of them all connected to 'master'? For doing this I obviously need two tasks, so I can scale one without scaling another. But then I do not know how processes running in one task can connect to a process running in another.

Comment: You can use services discover to connect two task

Comment: I know it is possible to do a 'task networking' to communicate between tasks (https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-cloud-native-networking-for-ecs-containers/) but I can't understand how to obtain the DNS name of a specific so another one can refer to it.

Comment: When you create task it will assign the DNS name too.